# How can I debug a request to a Connect server built through Grunt?

Tags: node.js, debugging, gruntjs, node.js-connect

I have a grunt task that builds a connect server, and connections to it are hanging. I want to know how to go about debugging this connection. It starts up the server without throwing errors, so I don't get them in my terminal window where I'm running the Grunt tasks. But no requests are coming back.

I try running grunt with '--debug' flag, and it prints `[D] server GET /api/loginRequest/ - - - - ms` but that's about it.

I've also tried putting code in the middleware and connect.js to throw a response early, but that's not cutting it...

My initConfig for the connect task looks like this:

```
    connect: {
        mockServer: {
            options: {
                livereload: true,
                port: 7770,
                hostname: 'localhost',
                middleware: [
                    function (connect, opt) {
                        var mocker = require('connect-api-mocker-adv'),
                            options = {
                                urlRoot: '/api',
                                pathRoot: 'mocks'
                            };

                        return [mocker(options)];
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your middleware config is based on the sample from [connect-api-mocker-adv](https://github.com/maxaon/connect-api-mocker-adv).  But that sample is targeted at **gulp-connect**, not **grunt-connect**. Translating it to grunt-connect middleware installation, I think it should look something like this:

```
connect: {
    mockServer: {
        options: {
            livereload: true,
            port: 7770,
            hostname: 'localhost',
            middleware: function(connect, options, middlewares) {
                var mocker = require('connect-api-mocker-adv'),
                    mockOptions = {
                        urlRoot: '/api',
                        pathRoot: 'mocks'
                    };
                middlewares.unshift(mocker(mockOptions));
                return middlewares;
            }
        }
    }
},
```